# I want to show that $\forall\,(x;y)\in\mathbb Z^2\,\big|\,x^2+y^2\geqslant1\implies |x|\geqslant1$ or $|y|\geqslant1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

$\forall\,(x;y)\in\mathbb Z^2\,\big|\,x^2+y^2\geqslant1\implies |x|\geqslant1$ or $|y|\geqslant1$.

I’d like to how to solve this. I tried everything.
What I tried so far is supposing that
$|x|\leqslant1$ and $|y|\leqslant1\implies x^2+y^2\leqslant1$.
So $x^2\leqslant1$ and $y^2\leqslant1$.
So by adding $\,x^2+y^2\leqslant2\,,\,$ I tried to see if the difference between the two is negative but I found nothing.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : try showing the result by contraposition : given $x$ and $y$ two integers, assume that "$|x| \geq 1$ or $y \geq 1$" is false, and try to prove that "$x^2+y^2 \geq 1"$ is false. Here how you should do this :

1. First translate ["$|x| \geq 1$ or $y \geq 1$" is false] into a simpler mathematical statement.
2. Then translate ["$x^2+y^2 \geq 1"$ is false] into a simpler mathematical statement.
3. Assume Statement (1), and try to prove Statement (2), remembering that $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Let's do it :

1. ["$|x| \geq 1$ or $y \geq 1$" is false] is equivalent to ["$|x| \geq 1$ is false" AND "$y \geq 1$" is false"], which is equivalent to [$|x| < 1$ AND $y < 1$]
2. ["$x^2+y^2 \geq 1"$ is false] is equivalent to : $x^2 + y^2 <1$.
3. Let $x$ and $y$ be two integers. Assume $|x| < 1$ AND $y < 1$. As $x$ in an integer with $|x| <1$, the only possible value for $x$ is $x=0$. As $y$ in an integer with $|y| <1$, the only possible value for $y$ is $y=0$. Thus $x^2+y^2 = 0^2 + 0^2 =0$, and we have $x^2 +y^2 < 1$.

We proved, for all integers $x$ and $y$ :
$$ \text{IF } "|x| \geq 1\text{ or }|y|\geq 1"\text{ is false, THEN }"x^2 +y^2 \geq 1"\text{ is false.}$$
By contraposition, we have for all integers $x$ and $y$ :
$$\text{IF } x^2 +y^2 \geq 1\text{, THEN }|x| \geq 1\text{ or }|y|\geq 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

How about this: Assume that $x^2+y^2 \geq 1$ but $|y| \not\geq  1$ (i.e., $y=0$). Then the assumption $x^2+y^2\geq 1$ immediately rearranges to $x^2 \geq 1$. This implies that $x\neq 0$, i.e., that $|x| \geq 1$.